# Web Services and Azure ACS - Security Token from an Identity Provider (e.g. Facebook)

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, azure, acs

I'm new to Azure ACS and working with a web site that implements Azure ACS. I need to write a web service that needs to be secured with authentication via an Identity Provider first (e.g. Facebook).

I'm having a hard time finding a simple sample that can help me accomplish basically the 2nd scenario laid out in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg429784.aspx ("By presenting a security token from another trusted issuer (Identity Provider) that has authenticated that client").

For what it's worth, I was able to find a great example that lets the client authenticate directly with ACS using ACS Service Identity (i.e. username/password) here: http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2013/06/25/protect-your-asp-net-web-api-using-azure-acs-service-identities/, but I need the client to authenticate via FB to identify who that client is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is also looking for this information, here's a sample I finally was able to obtain after contacting Microsoft Azure ACS support: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/AAL-Native-App-to-REST-de57f2cc